# C++/WinRT GattCharacteristic ValueChanged Event Never Fires / Triggers

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy, console-application, c++-winrt

The [`GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged` Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic.valuechanged?view=winrt-22000) never seems to fire in a very bare bones C++ / WinRT console application.

For device with config

- Local Name: `TestDevice`
- Advertised Service: `FFFF`
- Characteristic: `EEEE`

The following program will simply

- search for a device `TestDevice`
- find services of `TestDevice` with ShortID `FFFF`
- find the characteristic of that service with shortID `EEEE`
- [Write the ClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic.writeclientcharacteristicconfigurationdescriptorasync?view=winrt-22000) `GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue` to `EEEE`, which has property Read, Write and Notify
- register a lambda cast to `TypedEventHandler<GattCharacteristic,GattValueChangedEventArgs>` to `ValueChanged` which *should* print `New Value` on value update

Updating the characteristic value does not trigger the `ValueChanged` event. However, the same device setup has been tested with othe bluetooth stack with success.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.h>

using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothConnectionStatus;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothUuidHelper;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile;

using namespace winrt;


class WinBleCentral
{
public:
    WinBleCentral()
    {
        bleWatcher.Received(
            [this](BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                hstring testHstring{ std::wstring_view(L"TestDevice") };
                if (testHstring == eventArgs.Advertisement().LocalName())
                {
                    this->bleWatcher.Stop();
                    std::cout << "Matched\n";
                    BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress()).Completed(
                        [this](IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice> sender, AsyncStatus status)
                        {
                            if (auto device = sender.GetResults(); device)
                            {
                                std::cout << "Connected\n";
                                winrt::guid serviceGUID = BluetoothUuidHelper::FromShortId(0xFFFF);

                                device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(serviceGUID).Completed(
                                    [this](IAsyncOperation<GattDeviceServicesResult> sender, AsyncStatus status)
                                    {
                                        GattDeviceServicesResult result = sender.get();
                                        if (result && status == winrt::Windows::Foundation::AsyncStatus::Completed)
                                        {
                                            winrt::guid charGUID = BluetoothUuidHelper::FromShortId(0xEEEE);
                                            std::cout << "Num Services: " << result.Services().Size() << '\n';
                                            for (auto&& service : result.Services())
                                            {
                                                service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(charGUID).Completed(
                                                    [this](IAsyncOperation<GattCharacteristicsResult>sender, AsyncStatus status)
                                                    {
                                                        std::cout << "Get Characteristics\n";
                                                        if (auto result = sender.GetResults(); result)
                                                        {
                                                            std::cout << "Num Characteristics: " << result.Characteristics().Size() << '\n';
                                                            for (auto character : result.Characteristics())
                                                            {
                                                                character.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue::Notify).Completed(
                                                                    [this, character](IAsyncOperation<GattCommunicationStatus>sender, AsyncStatus status)
                                                                    {
                                                                        character.ValueChanged([this](GattCharacteristic characteristic, GattValueChangedEventArgs const& args)
                                                                            {
                                                                                std::cout << "New Value!\n";
                                                                            });
                                                                    });
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                );

                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        bleWatcher.Start();
    };

    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher bleWatcher;
};

int main()
{
    WinBleCentral bleCentral;
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Comment: Characterisit is notifiable or indicatable?

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Characteristic is indeed notfiable and has been tested successfully with another bluetooth stack

Comment: Have you tried it in Windows application? (not console)

Comment: Yes, and also the behaviour is the same

Comment: Does the device really have Client Configuration Descriptor? For example, DFRobot Bluno does not have one but sends notifications.

Comment: Also which stack did you test it with?

Comment: MacOS CoreBluetooth and yes the WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync returns with a successful status enum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242243/discussion-between-mike-petrichenko-and-fdcpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be down to the `GattCharacteristic` object falling out of scope. By simply keeping a reference of tha variable the above works as expected.

Below is the same program as above with the `Async` side of things stripped out to improve readability. I've tested and the exact same behaviour is displayed in both cases.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.h>

using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothConnectionStatus;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothUuidHelper;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs;
using winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile;

using namespace winrt;

class WinBleCentral
{
public:
 
    WinBleCentral()
    {
        std::cout << "Start\n";
        bleWatcher.Received(
            [this](BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                hstring testHstring{ std::wstring_view(L"TestDevice") };
                if (testHstring == eventArgs.Advertisement().LocalName())
                {
                    this->bleWatcher.Stop();
                    std::cout << "Matched\n";
                    auto device = BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress()).get();
                    std::cout << "Device\n";
                    winrt::guid serviceGUID = BluetoothUuidHelper::FromShortId(0xFFFF);
                    auto serviceResults = device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(serviceGUID).get();
                    std::cout << "Service Results\n";
                    winrt::guid charGUID = BluetoothUuidHelper::FromShortId(0xEEEE);
                    auto service = serviceResults.Services().GetAt(0);
                    std::cout << "Services\n";
                    auto characteristicResults = service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(charGUID).get();
                    std::cout << "Characteristic Results\n";
                    auto characteristic = characteristicResults.Characteristics().GetAt(0);
                    characteristics.push_back(characteristic);
                    std::cout << "Characterstic\n";
                    auto gattCommunicationStatus = characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue::Notify).get();
                    std::cout << "WriteClientCharacteristicConfiguration\n";
                    characteristic.ValueChanged([this](GattCharacteristic const& notifyingCharacteristic, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
                        {
                            std::cout << "New Value!\n";
                        });
                }
            });
        bleWatcher.Start();
    }

    std::vector<GattCharacteristic> characteristics;
    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher bleWatcher;
};


int main()
{
    WinBleCentral bleCentral;
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

even though  `std::vector<GattCharacteristic> characteristics` is never used, the simple act of `characteristics.push_back(characteristic)` is enough to keep a reference alive. This behaviour was definitely not expected.

To keep with the whole UWP style, I initially used the [`IVector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivector-1?view=winrt-22000) and the [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivector-1.append?view=winrt-22000#windows-foundation-collections-ivector-1-append(-0)) method, but the entire thing collapses at `check_hresult(WINRT_IMPL_SHIM(winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<T>)->Append(impl::bind_in(value)));` for what appears to be a null pointer.

For the above, all error checking has been eschewed for readability. Actual implementation should have healthy checking of all Async operations to make sure the data is actually there.